# jQuery delay() to start when you scroll to a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have delays in place within my div `gray`. I don't want those delays or animation to start until the user would scroll to that specific div. What I have tried doing is not working. The delays and animation still work, but they begin once the page loads.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```js
$(function() {
 var oTop = $('.gray').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
    
   var pTop = $('body').scrollTop();
     console.log( pTop + ' - ' + oTop );
   if( pTop > oTop ){
       textdelays();
   }
 });
});

$(function textdelays(){
  $('#text').delay(1000).fadeIn(2200);
  $('#text-button').delay(1000).fadeIn(2200);
  $('#text-button').animate({'top': '60%'}, 1000);
});
```

```css
.green {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
 }
 .yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
 }
.gray {
  background-color: #CCC;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
 }
#text {
  color: blue;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 25%;
  top: 35%;
  font-size: 1.3em;
 }
 #text-button {
   position: relative;
   wdith: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   top: 70%;
   display: none;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
 .border-span {
   border: 2px solid #FFF;
   padding: 15px 10px;
   color: #FFF;
   font-weight: bold;
 }
 .border-span:hover {
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #000;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="yellow"></div>
<div class="gray">
  <div id="text">text.</div>
  <div id="text-button"><span class="border-span">text animation</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are wrapping your `textdelays` function in `$()` which is the same as `$(document).ready`, so you are telling jQuery to execute that function once the DOM is ready. Just remove the wrapping `$()`

Comment: That did it. Thanks!